# Can you filter a column in Excel with data related to another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with two columns, both with dates in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. Is it possible to be able to filter the second column so that the dates in the second column represent one day after the date in the corresponding first column?

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper column.  If the dates are in columns **A** and **B**, then in **C2** enter:

```
=B2-A2
```

and copy downward

Then filter column **C** to display ***1*** only:

Before filtering:

[image]

and after filtering:

[image]